# Limit amount of results returned

Tags: posts, attachments

How can I limit the amount of results returned?

```
$images = $wpdb->get_col("
    SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE post_type = 'attachment'
    AND ID in ($meta)
    ORDER BY menu_order ASC
");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$images = $wpdb->get_col("
    SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE post_type = 'attachment'
    AND ID in ($meta)
    ORDER BY menu_order ASC
    LIMIT 5
");
```

Like @Kaiser suggested you can specify a range (5th to 20th results, a total of 15 results are returned at max) like this:

```
$images = $wpdb->get_col("
    SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE post_type = 'attachment'
    AND ID in ($meta)
    ORDER BY menu_order ASC
    LIMIT 5,20
");
```

Comment: thanks!  I didn't realize i had to put that at the END.

Comment: Deleted my answer as integrated here. @Ashfame Thanks. :) (should have been a comment here).

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Show_attachments_for_the_current_post)?

```
<?php
$attachments = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment', // post attachments
    'post_mime_type' => 'image', // only images
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,  // children of the current post
    'number_posts' => 5          // <-- THIS IS THE NUMBER OF POSTS LIMIT
) );
?>
```

I *always* prefer function calls to raw DB queries.

Comment: Even I prefer that but in some cases, we only need to fetch post IDs and we don't want WordPress to run a full query & cache it. This makes more sense when we are doing other than just displaying data :)

Comment: In which case, there's also [`get_children()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children). ;)

Comment: You misunderstood me. Think of doing an API call to a third party service only for posts matching a certain criteria. :)

Comment: I would consider a raw-SQL DB query to be the "third party API service call" in this scenario. Using a core-provided query function is generally safer, faster, more efficient, and more forward-compatible than making a raw-SQL DB query.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to @Ashfame Answer: You can not only set a "hard" limit, but also a *range*, using `LIMIT 1,100` which would bring you the results 1-100.